# Dataproc Hive Job - Tez Java heap OOM

Tags: java, hive, google-cloud-dataproc

I have a problem with my cluster.

the cluster have

- 2 worker primary
- 2 secondary worker
- 30 gb di ram

The cluster runs correctly and launches the job hives for at least about 10h.

After 10h I have an error of :Java heap space

```
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_292]
        Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
            at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3236) ~[?:1.8.0_292]
            at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:191) ~[?:1.8.0_292]
            at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ResponseBuffer.toByteArray(ResponseBuffer.java:53) ~[hadoop-common-3.2.2.jar:?]
            at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection$3.run(Client.java:1159) ~[hadoop-common-3.2.2.jar:?]
            ... 5 more
        ERROR : FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezTask
        INFO  : Completed executing command(queryId=hive_20210923102707_66b4cd11-7cfb-4910-87bc-7f062ce1b00e); Time taken: 75.101 seconds
        INFO  : Concurrency mode is   disabled, not creating a lock manager
Error: Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezTask (state=08S01,code=1)
```

i tried to set this cofiguration but it didn't help.

```
SET hive.execution.engine = tez; 
SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition = true; 
SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode = nonstrict; 
SET mapreduce.job.reduces=1;
SET hive.auto.convert.join=false;
set hive.stats.column.autogather=false; 
set hive.optimize.sort.dynamic.partition=true;
```

is there any way to clean the java heap space or I have got some configuration wrong?

the problem is solved by restarting the cluster

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the default Tez container and heap sizes set by Dataproc are too small for your job. You can update the following Hive properties to increase them:

**hive.tez.container.size**: The YARN container size in MB for Tez. If set to "-1" (default value), it picks the value of `mapreduce.map.memory.mb`. Consider increasing the value if the query / Tez app fails with something like "Container is running beyond physical memory limits. Current usage: 4.1 GB of 4 GB physical memory used; 6.0 GB of 20 GB virtual memory used. Killing container.". Example: `SET hive.tez.container.size=8192` in Hive, or `--properties hive:hive.tez.container.size=8192` when creating the cluster.

**hive.tez.java.opts**: The JVM options for the Tez YARN application. If not set, it picks the value of `mapreduce.map.java.opts`. This value should be less or equal to the container size. Consider increasing the JVM heap size if the query / Tez app fails with an OOM exception. Example: `SET hive.tez.java.opts=-Xmx8g` or `--properties hive:hive.tez.java.opts=-Xmx8g` when creating the cluster.

You can check `/etc/hadoop/conf/mapred-site.xml` to get the value of `mapreduce.map.java.opts`, and `/etc/hive/conf/hive-site.xml` for the 2 Hive properties mentioned above.